# Using Regex + BeautifulSoup to scrape XML and store to Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping some xml sites using beautifulSoup, and then storing the scraped data to a dataframe. The XML is usually consistently-formatted so the scraping works fine. But maybe 15% of the time, the data doesn't get saved to the dataframe because one of the prefixes is slightly different.

For example, when scraping these three URLs, the 2nd and 3rd ones gets stored to the dataframe without issue, whereas the 1st one doesn't.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

session = requests.Session()

# urls to loop through
form_urls = ['https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1418814/000141881220000017/vac13f021420.xml',
             'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/820124/000095012320003895/408.xml',
             'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1067983/000095012320002466/form13fInfoTable.xml']

# Create dataframe and set columns to match XML doc
cols = ['nameOfIssuer', 'titleOfClass', 'cusip', 'value', 'sshPrnamt',
        'sshPrnamtType', 'putCall', 'investmentDiscretion',
        'otherManager', 'Sole', 'Shared', 'None']

res_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)


# Iterate over URLs
for form_url in form_urls:
    data = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(session.get(form_url).content, 'lxml')
    print(soup)

    for info_table in soup.find_all(['ns1:infotable', 'infotable']):
        row = []
        for col in cols:
            d = info_table.find([col.lower(), 'ns1:' + col.lower()])
            row.append(d.text.strip() if d else 'NaN')
        data.append(row)
    url_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
    res_df = res_df.append(url_df, ignore_index=True)

print(res_df)
```

So how can I make the scraper more flexible in case the prefix is in an unexpected format (e.g., maybe it's an empty string or some other combination of uppercase and lower case letters and numbers)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First link you provided has second row as n1:infoTable not as ns1:infoTable, so for your code to work you need to take that to account.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re


session = requests.Session()

# urls to loop through
form_urls = ['https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1418814/000141881220000017/vac13f021420.xml',
             'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/820124/000095012320003895/408.xml',
             'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1067983/000095012320002466/form13fInfoTable.xml']

# Create dataframe and set columns to match XML doc
cols = ['nameOfIssuer', 'titleOfClass', 'cusip', 'value', 'sshPrnamt',
        'sshPrnamtType', 'putCall', 'investmentDiscretion',
        'otherManager', 'Sole', 'Shared', 'None']

res_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)


# Iterate over URLs
for form_url in form_urls:
    data = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(session.get(form_url).content, 'lxml')

    for info_table in soup.find_all(re.compile("([A-Za-z0-9]+:|)infotable")):
        row = []
        for col in cols:
            pattern = re.compile("([A-Za-z0-9]+:|)" + col.lower())
            d = info_table.find(pattern)
            row.append(d.text.strip() if d else 'NaN')
        data.append(row)
    url_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
    res_df = res_df.append(url_df, ignore_index=True)
```

Edit: Now prefix can be non existent (empty string '') or it can be combination of lowercase, uppercase letters and digits

Comment: Would this work for all permutations where the row starts with something like `n1:infoTable— like `ns1:infoTable`, `n:infoTable`, etc? I guess there might be slightly different variations per uRL so I'll need to be as flexible as possible.

Comment: If one URL has only one prefix (like n1 or ns1 or none) , then yes it will work on all URLs, you just need to set prefix in form_urls list. If that's not the case (one URL can have multiple prefixes like n1 and ns1 in different rows) you can try add list of prefixes instead of one prefix to form_urls and then iterate over that list of prefixes after that line with soup in your code.

Comment: I'm getting `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: Well, if you added list of prefixes to form_url then for loop is the same `for form_url, prefixes in form_urls:`, and then bellow soup you add `for prefix in prefixes`, everything else should stay the same.

Comment: Hmm I see, but I'm not always going to know the prefix for each URL, and I worry that adding it to the same list could cause issues down the line. So I think I'd need a different solution.

Comment: I would suggest you try regex then, especially when you don't know what prefixes will be.

Comment: `for form_url in form_urls:
    data = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(session.get(form_url).content, 'lxml')

    for info_table in soup.find_all(re.compile("([A-Za-z0-9]+:|)infotable")):
        row = []
        for col in cols:
            pattern = re.compile("([A-Za-z0-9]+:|)" + col.lower())
            d = info_table.find(pattern)
            row.append(d.text.strip() if d else 'NaN')
        data.append(row)
    url_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
    res_df = res_df.append(url_df, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: Do you mind adding that to your answer so that the formatting looks right? If it works, I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: I will, just do clarify the solution. Now prefix can be non existent (empty string '') or it can be combination of lowercase, uppercase letters and digits.

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick. It definitely runs a little slower though, but I guess that's the nature of using regex and perhaps something I will look into improving in the future.

Comment: Yeah, regex will slow it a bit. But in most cases it is a small price to pay for something as powerful as regex :)

Comment: Yeah I think it's good tradeoff for this program. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I agree. No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

In the first form_url you have "n1:..." tags.
That's why you have empty list.

You can try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

session = requests.Session()

# urls to loop through
form_urls = ['https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1418814/000141881220000017/vac13f021420.xml',
             'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/820124/000095012320003895/408.xml',
             'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1067983/000095012320002466/form13fInfoTable.xml']

# Create dataframe and set columns to match XML doc
cols = ['nameOfIssuer', 'titleOfClass', 'cusip', 'value', 'sshPrnamt',
        'sshPrnamtType', 'putCall', 'investmentDiscretion',
        'otherManager', 'Sole', 'Shared', 'None',]

res_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)


# Iterate over URLs
for form_url in form_urls:
    data = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(session.get(form_url).content, 'lxml')
    for info_table in soup.find_all(['n1:infotable', 'infotable']):
        row = []
        for col in cols:
            if form_url == form_urls[0]:
                col = "n1:" + col
            d = info_table.find([col.lower(), 'ns1:' + col.lower()])
            row.append(d.text.strip() if d else 'NaN')
        # print(row)
        data.append(row)
    print(data)
    print("==============================================")
    url_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
    res_df = res_df.append(url_df, ignore_index=True)

print(res_df)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to make this more flexible though, as I worry that there could be other variations of the prefix for the `infotable` that I may not have a list of in advance.